# Xcode debug issue

Tags: xcode

This problem has troubled me for a long time. When I debug my Swift project, I have to wait for a long time every time I enter a breakpoint. It takes about 1 minute to view variables and use the po command normally, which makes my daily work very painful. My computer is a MacBook Air M1 16G 256G SSD Xcode version 13.1. Did I ignore some settings about Xcode and look forward to an effective solution? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It depends on the complexity of your codes, and what else you are running on your Mac. Your new MacBook Air should not be that slow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried to run the demo project (SharingCloudKitDataWithOtherICloudUsers) downloaded from the official website. The problem is the same. So I wonder if the new macOS and Xcode have made some changes, because this problem appeared suddenly, and I used it before It’s MacBook Pro 2015. I thought it was caused by my old device, but I didn’t expect the problem to persist on the new Mac. The new Mac I did not make any personal settings are the default settings. By the way, I still use Android studio for M1. It works very well. Only Xcode has this problem.

Comment: This may be a general Xcode issue. I’ve noticed it being slower than I remember, even on my old 2019 MBP. Not a minute, but rather more like 30 seconds, but still painfully slow. When I get a chance, I’m going to download some old Xcode versions and see if it is my imagination, or whether it really is slower than old Xcode versions.

Comment: @Rob Yes, it’s also a lot slower than I remember, maybe because macOS and Xcode are getting bloated. I hope Apple’s engineers can use the entry-level Mac, which may be of great help to improving the Mac and software ecology.

Comment: In any case it's not a matter for Stack Overflow. It's a matter for Apple. Please do use Apple's developer feedback to complain about this.